# Duplicate postgresql columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, create-table

I want to duplicate postgresql data columns.

Let's say there is "id1" column and it has value of "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"

I want to duplicate column from "id1" to "id2"

"id2" column also has value of "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"

If it's possible please teach me how to do that.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

If the column does not exist to start with, then create it, with the same datatype as the original column (I assumed `text`).

```
alter table mytable add column id2 text;
```

Then, you can use a simple `update` statement to copy the content of the original column:

```
update mytable set id2 = id1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `select` query:

```
select id1, id1 as id2
from t;
```